# Is it safe to copy `ArrayList<E>` in this manner?

Tags: java, arraylist

This gives me a greater appreciation for immutable collections in Scala.

Let's say we have a Java static class that returns an `ArrayList<Integer>` of prime numbers between 1 and some specified cutoff. I started off with this:

```
package org.oeis.primes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimeLister {

    private static final ArrayList<Integer> PRIMES = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int currThresh;

    static {
        PRIMES.add(2);
        PRIMES.add(3);
        PRIMES.add(5);
        PRIMES.add(7);
        currThresh = 10;
    }

    // STUB TO FAIL THE FIRST TEST
    public static ArrayList<Integer> listPrimes(int threshold) {
        ArrayList<Integer> selPrimes = new ArrayList<>(PRIMES);
        return selPrimes;
    }

}
```

Then, go through a few cycles of TDD and get to a point where `listPrimes()` works reasonably well when `threshold` is greater than `currThresh`. To pass this test:

```
    @Test
    public void testPrimeListerCanTrim() {
        int threshold = 80;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = PrimeLister.listPrimes(threshold);
        System.out.println("PrimeLister reports " + result.size() 
                + " primes between 1 and " + threshold);
        threshold = 20;
        Integer[] smallPrimes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};
        ArrayList<Integer> expResult = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(smallPrimes));
        result = PrimeLister.listPrimes(threshold);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
```

`listPrimes()` needs to take a subset of `PRIMES`.

```
        // Not yet worried that threshold could be negative
        if (threshold < currThresh) {
            int trimIndex = PRIMES.size();
            int p;
            do {
                trimIndex--;
                p = PRIMES.get(trimIndex);
            } while (p > threshold);
            return new ArrayList<>(PRIMES.subList(0, trimIndex + 1));
        }
```

There's certainly a quicker way to find the correct `trimIndex` using the prime number theorem, but I'm not concerned about that at the moment. What I'm concerned about is this tidbit from the `subList()` Javadoc:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
>   ...
>   The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list.

I'm not quite understanding what this means. I tried changing the type of `listPrimes()` to `List<Integer>` and making it return `PRIMES` itself in both the `threshold < currThresh` and `threshold > currThresh` branches. And then I wrote this test:

```
    @Test
    public void testModifyPrimeSubset() {
        int threshold = 20;
        List<Integer> subset = PrimeLister.listPrimes(threshold);
        for (int i = 0; i < subset.size(); i++) {
            int p = -subset.get(i);
            subset.set(i, p);
        }
        threshold = 40;
        Integer[] smallPrimes = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37};
        ArrayList<Integer> expResult = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(smallPrimes));
        List<Integer> result = PrimeLister.listPrimes(threshold);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
```

As expected, returning `PRIMES` directly allows the caller to modify `PrimeLister`'s private prime number storage. One of my tests fails on account of getting −2, −3, −5, etc. The other tests cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Restoring the copies to new instances of `ArrayList<Integer>` gets all the tests passing again.

My question: Is this enough to prevent unintentional modifications to `PrimeLister`'s private prime number storage, or have I had a failure of the imagination?

Comment: You don't need all this. Just use [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).

Comment: @user207421 That's good enough for a toy example like this, not so much in a library intended for use by other people. Don't want them coming here asking why this thing they thought they could do with the sublist causes `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte People _won't_ expect to be able to modify the list if (1) you document that the list is unmodifiable and (2) you return a `List` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte So you want them to be able to modify the list but it has no effect? Is that really better than an exception? Do you really want them coming here asking why your sublist doesn't work *and not being able to get an answer?*

Comment: @user207421 They should be able to modify their copy of the list for whatever they want to do with it, without affecting the object the list came from.

Comment: Why? Is that intuitive? I don't think so. They will think they are modifying the prime-list or whatever it is: it won't work; and they will think your code is broken. Which it will be.

Comment: @user207421 It's intuitive if he'd rather be programming in Scala, where mutable collections require jumping through some hoops, whereas immutable collections are the default for most operations.

Answer (score 2):

So you're using a mutable collection to hold immutable objects, but those immutable objects wrap primitives, so there might be some boxing and unboxing involved. No wonder you're uncertain about this.

But look at the JDK source code. You can do this in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, and presumably other IDEs, too. Here's the relevant constructor:

```
    public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        if ((size = elementData.length) != 0) {
            // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
            if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
                elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
        } else {
            // replace with empty array.
            this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
        }
    }
```

Because of polymorphism, there are a few different possibilities of which `toArray()` gets called. However, there are certain guarantees that we can probably count on the authors of the JDK to uphold.

> `public abstract Object[] toArray()`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection. If this collection makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the same order.
>
> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by this collection. (In other words, **this method must allocate a new array even if this collection is backed by an array**). The caller is thus **free to modify the returned array**. [emphases mine]

So, as you already saw in your `testModifyPrimeSubset()`, by passing the sub-list through this particular `ArrayList` constructor, the caller can do whatever they need to do with the list and not worry about causing problems for `PrimeLister`.

Even if the integers don't get boxed and/or unboxed, the array backing the returned `ArrayList` is now independent of `PrimeLister`'s private prime number storage.

Lastly, I would like to note, with amusement, how ridiculous it is that `PrimeLister` should guard so jealously what is essentially public domain information. That's a comment on Java in general rather than on your program.